# nodejs async module exports

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am exporting a config js object asynchronously. How can I use the exported object in another module asynchronously?

```
   module.export = (async function(){
    connConf = await getDbConnectionConfiguration('administration_db');        
    const config = {
      development: {
      username: connConf.user,
      password: connConf.password,
      host: connConf.host,
      database: connConf.database}
    };   
  
    return config;
    })();
```

Then I am importing the above module in another object as below,

```
const configs = await require('../config');
```

But I am getting the error message saying **Unexpected reserved word 'await'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your config module: `module.export` should be `module.exports`.
Also, you are immediately calling your function on export and returning a pending Promise. It is better to remove last parenthesis and return the function itself:

```
//fixed typo V
module.exports = (async function(){
    connConf = await getDbConnectionConfiguration('administration_db');        
    const config = {
      development: {
        username: connConf.user,
        password: connConf.password,
        host: connConf.host,
        database: connConf.database
      }
    };   
  
    return config;
}); // <-- parenthesis removed here
```

`Unexpected reserved word 'await'` means that you are using `await` outside `async` function ("top-level awaits") and it can't be done in CommonJS (`.js`) modules.

One workaround is to wrap your code in an async function and call it:

```
const configsModule = require('./config'); // <-- your imported async function

async function init() {
    const configs = await configsModule();
    
    // all you code should be here now
    console.log(configs);
}

// call init
init();
```

Another way is to use top-level awaits if your Node is version 14 or above and you switch to ES modules (`.mjs`):

```
// app.mjs
import configsModule from '../config';

const configs = await configsModule();
```